# laravel visit error in route in the example in getting started with laravel 4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-routing

my source code is in
https://github.com/xsmyqf/startlaravel.git
in branch userauth.

I have a problem that when I visit localhost/startlaravel/public/cats/create it prints Page not found!
But the most confusing thing the page exactly exists in the folder and there is an cats/create route in the routes files!

the same route can be visited in branch master!I change nothing except add authentication.

thanks for any idea!

I have searched google but I really have no idea about why can't I visit the existing route!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in "#Laravel IRC channel",a man named trq help me solve the prolbem:

```
<trq> The reason is routes are processed in order. The cats/{cat} route matched but was unable to find anything by that id.
<xxs> cats/create can match /cats/{cat}
<xxs> cats/{cat} have )->where('id', '[0-9]+');
<trq> /cats/{cat} matches any string that looks like /cats/whateverthehellisthis
<xxs> cats/{cat} have )->where('id', '[0-9]+');
<xxs> only allow number
<trq> your not using id anywhere
<trq> that should likey be ->with('cat', '[0-9]+');
<xxs> oh!smart eyes
<xxs> I got it
<xxs> thanks very much
```

Comment: be aware that it is ->where('cat', '[0-9]+'); and not ->with!

Answer (score 1):

your path would be startlaravel/cats/create

if your installation directory is startlaravel if you have laravel in /var/www/ then you should visit

```
http://127.0.0.1/cats/create
```

or

```
http://127.0.0.1/cats
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to view it by going to

```
http://localhost/startlaravel/public/cats/create
```

in your browser (or something equivalent).

You're not going to want to visit `startlaravel/public/cats/create` but rather `cats/create`. So,

```
http://localhost/cats/create
```

The reason is, public is the root directory, not startlaravel.

Comment: you need try to enter project folder at least

Comment: Well it depends on how you set up your webserver. My root points directly to laravel's public directory.